# Delete icon doesn't do confirm dialog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy, button-to

I can't the "confirm" dialog to come up.  The record gets deleted ok and the page is updated, but no confirm dialog :(

```
= button_to('- - -', sched_set_path(sched_set_id), 
  :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this schedule?', 
  :method => :delete, 
  :action => :delete, 
  :class=> 'delete_icon')
```

Comment: hmm, seems to look right. Anything in the JS console?

Comment: good thought, unfortunately I checked and nothing relevant it semms, just some style issues with other stuff.

Comment: jquery_ujs.js is included as well?

Comment: hey that's it!  That fixed it!  Please post as answer and I will accept.

Comment: i.e. add //= jquery_ujs to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and `rake assets:precompile`.  I had //jquery_ujs - no '=' - so was was hard to see.

Comment: Actually now it takes two clicks on the pop-up but that's another issue I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ensure that `jquery_ujs.js` is included in your compiled javascript asset.

Comment: what if it is and still having an issue with the confirm dialog not showing?

Comment: Check the JavaScript console for any exceptions which stop execution.